# Any solution to determine whether two crash(raise an exception) was the same?

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, crash-reports, crashlytics

I was doing the Crash Report, and i don't want to collect every crash multiple times which was raised for the same reason, so how to find out the crash has been raised before?

Comment: You can use the Fabric SDK for Crash Reporting. Its will not show same crash for multiple time in list.

Comment: @Hiren，I need to collect the crash myself, and I wonder how they do this?